# Keep having the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when using map function in React js

Tags: reactjs

I've been struggling with this, and I don't even know what is wrong there. Here is an explanation for the codes below.

In `Slider` component, I get `storeList` from parent component as props, and pass it to `RenderSlider`.

```
const Slider = (props) => {
   const { storeList } = props;
   return (
       ....
       <RenderSlider storeList={storeList} />
       ...
   );
}
```

In `RenderSlider`, I get `storeList` from `Slider`, and then it prints `storeList` to double check if it has data inside. Like you see the most bottom image, it has 10 stores. However, the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` happens in the code line using `map()` function. The array has a correct data inside and its type is also printed as `object` to be array. I tried to debug it with tons of times, but I can't find the reason. Can anyone help me for this?

```
const RenderSlider = props => {
  console.log(props.storeList);
  console.log(typeof props.storeList);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.storeList.map(store => ( <--- ERROR happens in this line
        <span key={store.id}>{store.businessName}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's rendering before the props are there.  Add an `if` check for the `storeList` before you do the `map`.

Comment: ...{props.storeList && props.storeList.map ...

Comment: @jmargolisvt Like you see the `console.log(props.storeList);` in the second line in `RenderSlider`. I printed out `storeList` and it shows correct data in the most bottom image. Also, I tried `console.log()` in return statement, and it shows the same.

Comment: @Idan wow, that works! Why do I need to have `props.storeList &&` before map()?

Comment: Because `props.storeList` is undefined, which is what the error message is saying.

Comment: Is it different with `console.log()`? Since `console.log()` prints the array properly, I thought it's not undefined

Comment: I suspect that you are rendering a different `<RenderSlider />` somewhere else, and not passing in a `storeList` prop. Do you see any `undefined` in the console log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that there is array before you use map:

In this nice syntax you can just verify that `props.storeList` is not undefined/null...

```
const RenderSlider = props => {
  console.log(props.storeList);
  console.log(typeof props.storeList);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.storeList && props.storeList.map(store => ( <--- ERROR happens in this line
        <span key={store.id}>{store.businessName}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: That helped me a lot! Thank you so much! @Idan

Comment: `&&` is not a new syntax. That's been in javascript since the beginning, and in C for the last half century.

Comment: Hi @HåkenLid, nice not new. Deleted ES6, since I am not sure. Feel free to edit...

Comment: There is a proposed "Optional Chaining Operator" which could be used here. But it's only stage 1, so it might not end up in the language. It would look like this: `props.storeList?.map(...)` and would return `undefined` if `storeList` is `null` or `undefined`. A difference from `&&` is that other falsy values such as `false` or `0` would not short circuit, so you would get an exception if you passed in a value of a completely incorrect type.

Comment: That would be nice, just tested it, not working yet.

Comment: Yeah, OP should use proptypes for that, different discussion

Comment: Stage 1 means there's no browser support yet. But it's possible to use it in your code, if you are willing transpile with  bleeding edge Babel presets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const RenderSlider = props => {
  const {storeList} = props;
  if (!storeList) return null;

  if (
  return (
    <div>
       {props.storeList.map(store => (
       <span key={store.id}>{store.businessName}</span>
    ))}
    </div>
```

);
};

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `storeList` gets data from somewhere and by the time `Slider` renders, it's not there yet.

Please don't be fooled by Chrome logging, if you click on the [i] icon, you can see the data's just arrived and it logs after rendering.

I think adding your storeList is empty/null before rendering will fix the problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the log comes after rendering. Thank you for the tip!